# FreeGlut (Similar to OpenGL) is taking picture of my desktop instead of drawing shapes

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, freeglut

Genpfault helped me tremendously is getting my code to compile. The code below is a reduced version of what I'm currently working with. However, Glut is not letting me draw shapes. The only thing that happens when I run the executable after compiling is that I see a screenshot of my desktop.

How can I remedy this so that I can actually draw colorful triangles and polygons on a black screen? [Screenshot of what the program looks like when it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlTEd.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

namespace GameBoxes
{
    template<class T>
    class Box
    {
        public:
            void display( void );
    };
} //GameBoxes

namespace GameBoxes
{
    template <class T>
    void Box<T>::display( void )
    {
        glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );       // black background
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        glColor3f( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
        glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
        glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
        glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
        glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
} // GameBoxes

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );

    int windowPos1 = 0, windowPos2 = 0, windowSize1 = 400, windowSize2 = 400;
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowPosition( windowPos1, windowPos2 );
    glutInitWindowSize( windowSize1, windowSize2 );
    glutCreateWindow( "square" );

    GameBoxes::Box<double> square;

    glutSetWindowData( &square );
    glutDisplayFunc( []()
    {
        auto instance = static_cast< GameBoxes::Box<double>* >(    glutGetWindowData() );
        instance->display();
    } );
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Um, I don't know how to say this, but: This is among the most convoluted ways to implement a GLUT display callback I've seen so far. I mean, sure, it works. But calling `glutSwapBuffers` inside the drawing method of a class that's there to represent some kind of graphical primitive is just outright weird. In fact, why is it, that so many people seem to have this strong urge to wrap *__everything__* into classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to finish the [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence with `glEnd`

```
template <class T>
void Box<T>::display( void )
{
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );       // black background
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
    glEnd();  // <-------------- add glEnd
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

---

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

Comment: I'll look into that, but when I add glEnd(); the program produces a black screen. No shapes are drawn at all. I think the data isn't getting through successfully.

Comment: @Kalkirin Weird, I can see a dark gray triangle.

Comment: No that's my fault. forgot to add the color. it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my oversight